# padding and floating issues with nav bar

Tags: php, html, css

I've been trying to do two things with my code, firstly I've been trying to get rid of the small annoying line underneath my selected nav links and also trying to float both the header and footer to the right without losing my header and footer backgrounds.

I've added some basic PHP to my html to improve efficiency. Could someone please have a quick look at my code, I've been rackinh my brains over this for hours and starting to think I'm really over thinking the problem. Thanks in advance :D

```css
/*********************************************
Header & Footer
*********************************************/
.header,
.footer {
 max-width: 80%;
 background: #191A1C;
 margin: auto;
}
.header .nav,
.footer .nav{
 text-align: center;

}
.header .nav ul,
.footer .nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: auto 0;
}
.header .nav li,
.footer .nav li{
 display: inline-block;
}

/*********************************************
Links
*********************************************/
.header .nav li a:link,
.header .nav li a:visited,
.footer .nav li a:link,
.footer .nav li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
 background: #404247;
 color: #E8EBF5;
}
.header .nav li,
.header .nav li a:link,
.header .nav li a:visited{
 padding: 1em 2em;
}
.footer .nav li,
.footer .nav li a:link,
.footer .nav li a:visited{
 padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
.header .nav li a:hover,
.footer .nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*********************************************
Selected Links
*********************************************/
.header .nav  li.home_on a,
.footer .nav li.home_on a{
 background: #BC4663;
}
.header .nav  li.portfolio_on a,
.footer .nav li.portfolio_on a{
 background: #80C7F2;
}
.header .nav  li.aboutMe_on a,
.footer .nav li.aboutMe_on a{
 background: #CCC331;
}
.header .nav  li.contactMe_on a,
.footer .nav li.contactMe_on a{
 background: #64CE97;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li class="home <?php if ($section == "home") {echo "home_on";} ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li class="portfolio <?php if ($section == "portfolio") {echo "portfolio_on";} ?>"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li class="aboutMe <?php if ($section == "aboutMe") {echo "aboutME_on";} ?>"><a href="aboutMe.php">About Me</a></li>
   <li class="contactMe <?php if ($section == "contactMe") {echo "contactMe_on";} ?>"><a href="contactMe.php">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've more or less sorted the issue I was having. To float my nav bar to the right whilst keeping my background intact I had to wrap it in a container and re arrange some of my css. I also added a :after statement to my header to clear anything that will be floating after my nav.

```css
/*********************************************
Header & Footer
*********************************************/
.wrapper{
 max-width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
}
.header,
.footer {
 background: #191A1C;
}
.header:after,
.footer:after {
 content:"";
 height:0;
 display:block;
 visibility:hidden;
 clear:both;
}
.header .nav,
.footer .nav{
 text-align: center;
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
}
.header .nav ul,
.footer .nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: auto 0;
}
.header .nav li,
.footer .nav li{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <ul class="nav">
    <li class="home <?php if ($section == "home") {echo "home_on";} ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="portfolio <?php if ($section == "portfolio") {echo "portfolio_on";} ?>"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="aboutMe <?php if ($section == "aboutMe") {echo "aboutME_on";} ?>"><a href="aboutMe.php">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="contactMe <?php if ($section == "contactMe") {echo "contactMe_on";} ?>"><a href="contactMe.php">Contact Me</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
```